# Design/Text tab is not showing only for drawable resource files

Tags: android

I am new to Android studio Text/Design Tab Missing for only XML file created in drawable resources folders and yes I've tried invalidate cache/restart option but it is not working

Activity.xml ScreenShot:
[image: Activity.xml ScreenShot]

Button.xml ScreenShot:
[image: Button.xml ScreenShot]

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find `Preview` on the right side of the window:
[image: Preview]

Or you can enable this window using menu:
`View -> Tool Windows -> Preview`:

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 1):

`Design/Text` tab is intended for designing `layout` XML resources only. And the `drawables` XML resources are not same as layout, they are mostly defined as `selector`, `shape`, etc which **never** contain any UI elements like `TextView`, `ImageView` which needs to be designed. So Android Studio doesn't feel it necessary to put that `Design/Text` tab for `drawables` XML resources too.

However you can try using the **Preview** option to have your work preview, as @Boken mentioned in the another answer.